# How to add external dependency?

Tags: hardhat

Hardhat is truly a boon for testing interplay with ETH contracts. Yet there are some drawbacks, e.g. it's quite unclear how to use it without contracts. Say I just want to interact with some interfaces of already deployed contracts in the fork mode. How should I go about it?

An attempt to use external libraries wound up at the following error:

```
ERROR: HardhatError: HH700: Artifact for contract "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol" not found.
```

**scripts/new.ts**

```
import { ethers } from "hardhat";

//import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

//const IERC20_SOURCE = "openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol:IERC20";
const IERC20_SOURCE = "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
const AAVE_POOL_SOURCE = "aave-v3-core/contracts/protocol/pool/Pool.sol";

const WBTC = '0x2260FAC5E5542a773Aa44fBCfeDf7C193bc2C599';
const USDT = '0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7';

const WBTCUSDT = '0x9Db9e0e53058C89e5B94e29621a205198648425B';

const WBTC_OWNER = '0x8EB8a3b98659Cce290402893d0123abb75E3ab28'; //'0x9ff58f4fFB29fA2266Ab25e75e2A8b3503311656';
const USDT_OWNER = '0x47ac0Fb4F2D84898e4D9E7b4DaB3C24507a6D503';

const AAVE_POOL = '0x87870Bca3F3fD6335C3F4ce8392D69350B4fA4E2';

async function main() {
  const get_erc20 = async (addr, signer) => {
    const erc20 = await ethers.getContractAt(IERC20_SOURCE, addr, signer);
    return erc20.connect(signer);
  };
  const get_aave_pool = async (addr, signer) => {
    const aave_pool = await ethers.getContractAt(AAVE_POOL_SOURCE, addr, signer);
    return aave_pool.connect(signer);
  };

  await hre.network.provider.request({
    method: "hardhat_impersonateAccount",
    params: [WBTC_OWNER],
  });

  const wbtc_owner = await ethers.getSigner(WBTC_OWNER);
  const wbtc = await get_erc20(WBTC, wbtc_owner);
  const usdt = await get_erc20(USDT, wbtc_owner);

  const aave_pool = await get_aave_pool(AAVE_POOL, wbtc_owner);

  await hre.network.provider.request({
    method: "hardhat_stopImpersonatingAccount",
    params: [WBTC_OWNER],
  });
}

main()
  .catch(el => void console.error('ERROR:', el))
```

How should I rectify the error?

Comment: You are right, you need to create a contract that imports from that external OZ reference to then attach it to the deployed instance of that ERC20

Comment: Check your imported package path in node_modules, If it exists or not. Sometimes, it might change according to the version of the package.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting seems to be related to the inability to find the artifact for the IERC20 interface. This usually happens when your interface is not connected properly to your file or your File is Not in the same directory!

1 . So Make Shure you have Installed it! you need to install the OpenZeppelin Contracts library, which can be done using npm (or yarn) by running the following command in your terminal:

if you using npm then type this

```
npm install @openzeppelin/contracts
```

for yarn

```
 npm install @openzeppelin/contracts
```

2. Make sure this file has the same directory as which node_module folder present
3. If you facing still this issue or error..then try uploading like this

   import "../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

Comment: The idea of the question is how should a hardhat project use an already deployed contract with only the contract interface, like IERC20.sol, and the deployed address. If it is possible without compiling a contract.

Comment: you need to deploy the contract on the hardhat network first. then they interface work

Answer (score 0):

you have to import artifacts not contracts. Artifacts are Json files that create after compiling smart contracts and they are in the build directory, in OZ you can import them in this directory:

> node_modules@openzeppelin\contracts\build\contracts\ERC20.json

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the error you are getting is related to the inability to find the artifact for the IERC20 interface. This usually happens when the required package is not installed or not linked properly.

To resolve this, you can try the following steps:

1. Make sure you have installed the required package. In this case, it seems like you need to install the OpenZeppelin Contracts library, which can be done using npm (or yarn) by running the following command in your terminal:npm
   -> **install @openzeppelin/contracts**
2. If the package is already installed, you can try removing the node_modules folder and reinstalling all packages using the following commands:
   ->**rm -rf node_modules**
   npm install
3. If the issue persists, you can try linking the package using the following command: -> npm link @openzeppelin/contracts
4. If none of the above steps work, you can try importing the required interface directly from the node_modules folder by uncommenting the following line in your code: ->   **// import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";**
5. and replacing it with:

import **"../../../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";**

Answer (score 0):

Your hardhat script(node.js) seeks a compiled artifact, not a solidity file. So you need to compile it at least once somewhere in your project.

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol"
...
contract MyContract {
...
}
```

```js
...
const IERC20_SOURCE = "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol:IERC20";
...
const erc20 = await ethers.getContractAt(IERC20_SOURCE, addr, signer);
...
```

This will work.